# Configure DBCP inside of Tomcat

Tags: tomcat7, apache-commons-dbcp

I am trying to inject DataSource into Servlet. Finally I've annotated datasource field with @Resource and some DBCP's BasicDataSource was injected there. But it has no configuration. No db url, no driver class, nothing. Naturally I got NullPointerException when trying to `getConnection()`. What am I doing wrong?

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ua.test.TestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/serve</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/MyDB</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <injection-target>
            <injection-target-class>ua.test.TestServlet</injection-target-class>
            <injection-target-name>dataSource</injection-target-name>
        </injection-target>
    </resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Context>

    <Resource name="jdbc/MyDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="10" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
              username="tomcat" password="tomcat" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>

</Context>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously no one gave a sh*t about my sorrow. So I will answer myself.
Tomcat has it's own(probably modified) copy of Apache Commons DBCP under package `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc`, but also for some stupid reason includes original DBCP under `org.apache.commons.dbcp` package. What happens when I try to inject Datasource with `@Resource` annotation is Tomcat instanting Datasource from original package and injecting this instance to my field. To make Tomcat to use his own copy of DBCP I had to modify my `context.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDB"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
              auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="10" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
              username="tomcat" password="tomcat"  
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
</Context>
```

Basicaly I just added this line:

```
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
```

Thanks to everyone who knew the reason but ignored this question for so long time :-)

Comment: Nope... don't care for your sorrow... but sure appreciate your answer ;)